# C# how to get key input in background?

Tags: c#

I want to get key input in c#.net in console application but the console will be invisible like freeconsole in c# and it will get what you type and set it to a string named like idk input then messagebox.show(input); then everytime you type a key it messagees it in the background,
i want to learn to make games so yeah and i want it to work in background.

Comment: so yeah I think that sounds kewl.  Let us know how you go buddy

Comment: So you want to create an invisible keylogger?

Answer (score 0):

The way Windows works is that when a key on the keyboard is hit, Windows sends a message (actually, several) to the Window which currently has the focus. If your Console app is in the background, then by definition it will not have the focus.

All is not lost, though. You can setup what's called a [global keyboard hook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C). This does mean that you'll get ALL keyboard hits, though.

And as @AaronM.Eshbach says, this is a keylogger and generally not a good thing...

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_.  I was going to say something like don't feed dubious people too but if OP can't work this out, I feel the world is safe from another keylogger ;)